# How do I relace fields with "yes" or "no" in Crystal Reports based on whether they have a value?

Tags: syntax, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

All I want to do is change everything in a field that has a value to "Yes" and everything that does not have a value to "No".

I've tried this:

```
if {CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Description} = "" then "No" else "Yes";
```

But I get an error saying, "The result of selection formula must be a boolean."

If I try:

```
IF {CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Description} = TRUE then "Yes" else "No";
```

Then I get a error that says, "A string is required here."

This should be a simple thing, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula works, I was just putting it in the wrong place.

How I got it to work:

I was trying to attach the formula to the CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Description field, which is wrong.

I needed to create a **New Formula Field**. In the Field Explorer, right click on formula fields and click, "New..." Name the new field, paste the code in there (`if {CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Description} = "" then "No" else "Yes";`) then Save. Drag the new formula field into the report instead of the CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Description field, and voila.

Copy and paste

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative solution to display Yes/No instead of string/Boolean.
1. Right click on the field in your report and select Format Editor 
2. Click on the formula button on the right of Display String row.
3. Paste your formula and Save.

This will do pretty much the same as Formula field. The only downside of this approach is if you will generate Excel Data only report, it will generate report field with original field values (string or True/False)

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. create new formula and drag it to the report, as suggested;
2. or on the same field "..Description" right click > select Format Field and in the Format Editor window, click the formula icon near "Display String" and insert the same formula that evaluates if the field = "" or not.